# insert msg object to mongodb (node-red)?

Tags: mongodb, node-red

We're experimenting with storing data to a MongoDB by using node-red. As it is now, we can store data on the database, but it seems like only the 'msg.payload' is stored (as document) - and not the whole msg object. Which confuses us a little...

The flow is very simple and nothing much has really been done.

[image]

We actually dont need *ALL* data, but we  wish to store **payload** but also **metadata** as a document to our collection on our database. We've tried searching for an answer to this, but couldn't find anything relevant on how to do this. Hopefully we can get some help on this forum.

Thanks in advance! (btw. we're using mongodb3 on node-red to store data)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The node you are using is working as intended.

The normal pattern for Node-RED is that the focus of any given node is the `msg.payload` entry, any other `msg` properties are considered to be meta data.

The simplest thing here would be to use the built in core change node to move the other fields you are interested in to be properties of the `msg.payload` object.